# Disposing of COM object from c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, dispose

I have read several articles/posts on correctly disposing of COM objects when interacting from .NET. Normally i don't have a problem.. but i keep getting orphaned COM objects after closing my following program.I don't know if it has something to do with the addin i am opening.

```
        Application app = new Application();
        Workbooks wrks = app.Workbooks;
        Workbook wrk = null;
        Workbook wrkAddin = null;
        Sheets shts = null;
        Range rng = null;           

        try
        {
            app.ScreenUpdating = true;
            app.Visible = true;
            app.DisplayAlerts = false; // stop any dialog boxes appearing.. such as save or debug when loading bloomberg addin.
            wrk = wrks.Open(Filename: MasterPriceFiles.Properties.Resources.strETFDataFullPath, ReadOnly: false,Editable: true, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended: true);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            wrkAddin = wrks.Open(Filename: MasterPriceFiles.Properties.Resources.strBloombergAddinPath); // have to explicitly open the bloomberg addin
            app.Visible = true;
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            shts = wrk.Worksheets;
            foreach (Worksheet sht in shts)
            {
                rng = sht.UsedRange;
                rng.Copy();
                rng.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sht);
            }
            app.Visible = false;
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            wrk.SaveAs(Filename: MasterPriceFiles.Properties.Resources.strETFDataMacroFreeFullPath, ConflictResolution: XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, AccessMode: XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully saved ETF price data sheet at . " + DateTime.Now.ToString());


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error refreshing ETF price date. " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rng != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(rng);
            if (shts != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shts);
            wrk.Close(SaveChanges: false);
            if (wrk != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wrk);
            wrkAddin.Close(SaveChanges: false);
            if (wrkAddin != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wrkAddin);
            if (wrks != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wrks);
            app.Quit();
            if (app != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
```

Comment: You should really wrap disposable entities with a `using() { }` clause to restrict their scope and ensure their correct cleanup. Also note that you try to close `wrt` before you check it for null.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts COM objects are not disposable

Comment: it could be the addin that you are opening not properly releasing all the COM objects and you can do nothing about it

Comment: And what about the `wrk.Close()` before checking it for `null`. This could raise an exception and leave the subsequent resources in limbo.

Comment: `rng.Copy()` returns an object. If that is not null, then you need to release that.

Comment: Also, it is possible that you release `rng` twice, once in the `foreach` block and one in the `finally` block. I am not sure what is the effect of this. I think you should release a COM object only once.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I looked at the rng.Copy(), but it only returns a boolean, whether or not the copy was successful.

I will change the code to only close the workbook if it is not null, thanks.

Any suggestions on what it could be with the addin i am opening?